# How to loop through data and print into same column one after another?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

This is my first post so sorry if its incorrect.

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
worksheet.write('A1', 'Subjects')

for msg in mbox:
    try:
        print (msg['subject'])
    except:
        print("error")

workbook.close()
```

At the moment i have a heading of Subject in A1. How can i print the msg['subject'] under the heading in A2,A3,A4 and so on.?

I think i have answerd my own question. This is what i did and it worked:

```
i = 2
for msg in mbox:
      try:
           worksheet.write('A{}'.format(i), msg['subject']
           i = i+1
```

Comment: mbox is a file of emails. msg is a dictionary i think. so msg['To'] will contain the email address of who the email is to. msg['subject'] contains the subject and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `enumerate()` to index your messages:

```
for row, msg in enumerate(mbox, start=1):
    worksheet.write(row, 0, msg['subject'])
```

Note that we need to start enumerating from 1, because in xlsxwriter row and column indexing starts from 0 and we want to start writing from the second row (A2).